# Am I leaking memory or not?

Tags: c++, memory, crt

Ok here are the basic facts, when I start my program I look at the "Task Manager" it always has the same.

```
Memory(active private working set)  Memory(private working set)
           1,412K                            1,412k
```

That not bad about 1M when it first starts up, and that is a stable numbers. Now I need to check for memory leaks so I execute the following.

```
        _CrtMemState checkPt1, checkPt2, checkPt3;
        _CrtCheckMemory();
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&checkPt1);
        ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        ClientSocket =  CurrentClass->AcceptIPV4();
        if (ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
            thread (SubThread, CurrentClass, ClientSocket).join();
        }
        _CrtCheckMemory();
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&checkPt2);
        _CrtMemDifference(&checkPt3, &checkPt1, &checkPt2);
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&checkPt3);
        _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&checkPt1);
```

Now this working GOOD it does not hender my thread at all. The thread execute and get a report as follows.

```
The thread 0x4470 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
8924 bytes in 22 Free Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Normal Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 0 bytes.
Total allocations: 8924 bytes.
Dumping objects ->
Object dump complete.
```

This is GOOD news I looks like every byte that was allocated is being freed. Now comes the trouble, when I look at "Task Manager" I see the following.

```
  Memory(active private working set) Memory(private working set)
            1,652K                          1,652k
```

This has increased all of 225k after running just that one thread. Fact every time this thread is executed "Task Manager" show an increase of about 225k. So am I leaking memory or not. I have whent throu every line of code it that thread, everywhere I use malloc it has a free, and everywhere I use new it has a delete that gos whith it. Can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: *everywhere I use malloc it has a free, and everywhere I use new it has a delete that gos whith it* -- Unless this is a toy program, looking at code this way is not definitive as to whether you have memory leaks or not.  What if the "new" calls are conditional, and the "delete" calls are conditional?  What if there is a bug, and you're calling `new` in a loop `n` times, but calling `delete` a different number of times, even though visibly, there is 1 `new` and 1 `delete` call?

Comment: Don't use task manager to tell you the memory usage. Is valgrind an option? Are you using VS? If so, you can use it's memory usage tool...

Comment: The CRT only tracks its own allocations; direct Win32 allocations (e.g. for network buffers) aren't tracked by the CRT. Did you also check all `CloseHandle`? We don't see all your code here.

Comment: [MemorySanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html)? [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)? [LeakSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html)?

Comment: Memory Use/Error Check programs like Valgrind on Linux are OS specific when they run. All OS have somewhat of an equivalent tool. gcc (and clang) can compile with debug symbols left in the executable that allows valgrind to execute the resulting executable within its process and track the allocations from the program while attempting to mask the system allocations that you don't control. VS has something similar, though I haven't used it. There are also other utilities for windows that others will have to help identify. Task Manager isn't one of them. So we can't tell based on your post.

Comment: Yes, I am using CRT to check for memory leaks. The thread closes all handlers.

Comment: Yes, I am using CRT to check for memory leaks. The thread closes all handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Valgrind if on Linux and Dr. Memory if on Windows. VS has some sort of memory monitor but I haven't looked into it too much. Dr. Memory has worked for me pretty ok, as it's similiar to Valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you must call EmptyWorkingSet(GetCurrentProcess()); this function for "Task Manager" to give the correct numbers. Otherwise "Task Manager" doesn't catch all the freed memory. This is case most of time when you lock the current heap with thread id.

By the way I have no memory losses at all....